# hover и два блока

Tags: jquery, меню

Доброго времени суток!

Такой вопрос.
Есть простое меню

```
<ul>
<li class="m1" id="a_1"><a href="">ссыль</a></li>
<li class="m2" id="a_2"><a href="">ссыль</a></li>
<li class="m3" id="a_3"><a href="">ссыль</a></li>
<ul>
```

И есть три блока

```
<div id="aa_1">m1</div>
<div id="aa_2">m2</div>
<div id="aa_3">m3</div>
```

Суть такова, что при наведении на ссыль с определенным классом, должен открываться определенный блока. ну эт понятно.

Вопрос в том, как заставить у ссылок держать hover, когда мышка уже перейдет на область блока?

Т.е. это горизонтальное, выпадающее меню. При наведении на определенный пункт меню, выпадает определенный блок, в котором есть контент и ссылки... Т.е. человек наводит на пункт меню мышку, она выделяется(так как сработал hover) и далее уже двигает мышку к самому блоку. И вот тут как раз у пункта меню не должен пропадать hover и див не должен закрываться.

Как-то можно обыграть это используя jQuery? (подключен уже)

зы. Сейчас пока писал пришла в голову идея о том, чтобы проверять, на блоке ли мышка и если на блоке то добавлять к пункту меню выделение.

Пошел пробовать. Но за идеи буду благодарен!

**UPD**

Сделал так

```
$("li").hover(function()
{
    if (menu = $(this).attr('id'))
    {
        var menuId = menu.split('_');
        $('#aa_'+menuId[1]).toggle();
    }
});
```

Выпадает корректно.
Но остается вопрос в том, как заставить НЕ закрываться див, когда убираешь мышку с пункта меню.

Вот, что в итоге вышло http://jsfiddle.net/3ehGE/

**Deonis** спасибо!
не знаю почему, но нет кнопок ответить и не нашел как писать личные сообщения, хотел сказать спасибо.

Comment: @Deonis спасибо!
Скажите, а можно сделать как-то там задержку.
Т.е. например человек навел мышку и через пару сек выпадает меню.
Потому как при каждом движении мышки через это меню оно будет туда-сюда открываться\закрываться.
Сейчас как раз читаю про stop(), setTimeout...

Что-то не могу ответить на коммент ниже. не вижу кнопки...

Comment: @Deonis а как быть, если первая ссылка без дива своего?
Получается так, что он поочередно открывает.

Comment: @dropoff, вы практически уже ответили на свой вопрос. [Добавляете метод stop()](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3ehGE/4/)

Comment: немного не так.
Т.е. человек навел и ждет пару сек, а только потом открывается меня.
В приведенном Вами примере все равно при быстром движении мышки меню открывается быстро. Будет не красиво моргать при каждом проводе мышки быстро.

Comment: Ага... Ну, для этого можно использовать или же, как вы сказали setTimeout(), или же есть метод [delay()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: как я понял делей просто оттягивает время. т.е. меню вылезет в любом случае через отведенное время.(хотя может не понял до конца).
Буду копаться. Спасибо.

А вот на счет пунктов меню у которых не предусмотрены выпадающие блоки... Что-то можно сделать, чтобы он не поочередно их открывал, а по ID этих блоков?

Comment: @dropoff, у вас есть достаточно приемлемый вариант, где элементы связываются по каким-то данным, взятым из их атрибутов. Можете свой атрибут сделать, дабы не было накладок. К примеру:

    <li class="m3" data-target="3"></li>

И не надо добавлять еще какие-то "суффиксы".

P.S. Кстати, забыл добавить, что используя атрибут **data-***, данные в jQuery можно получить так:

    $('li').data('target'); // вернет 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
.hidden.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

js:

```
$("li").hover(function()
{
    if (menu = $(this).attr('id'))
    {
        var menuId = menu.split('_');
        $('#aa_'+menuId[1]).toggleClass('visible');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ehGE/6/)

Ещё убрал белую полоску, и имейте ввиду, что если длинное главное меню будет, то будет попасть в это нижнее меню будет невозможно, делайте relative позицию, и `delay()` на скрытие, если полоска так уж нужна, используйте блок `:before` в css [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/3ehGE/7/)

вариант с блэкджеком:

```
$("li").hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var menu;
    if ((menu = $this.attr('id'))) {
        var menuId = menu.split('_');
        var target = $('#aa_' + menuId[1]);
        target.toggleClass('visible');
        if (!target.is(":visible")) {
            $this.removeClass('active');
            target.unbind('mouseover');
        } else $this.addClass('active');
        target.one('mouseover', function () { //если навели то
            target.one('mouseout', function mouseout() { //после наведения убрали мышь 
                if (target.is(':hover')) { //все еще в том же дереве ?
                    target.one('mouseout', mouseout); // повесить заново хэндлер 
                    return true; // вернуться
                }
                $this.removeClass('active'); //убрали совсем мышь из подменю ? скрыть
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Очевидное рядом. Спасибо))
А как можно для пунктов меню добавить активный класс, когда определенный див открыт?
Т.е. когда я навел мышку на a_1 она стала активной. Но когда перемещаю мышку в сам блок, то пропадает ховер у a_1.

Comment: [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3ehGE/11/)

Comment: @dropoff смотри пред коммент

Comment: вот как в js приделать позиционирование 
(http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3ehGE/12/)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось.

Comment: не сразу заметил.
В дивах есть содержимое. Так вот если навести мышку на содержимое, то класс active пропадает.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3ehGE/16/ вот так пофиксить можно

Comment: Большущее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vRs9E/ примерно так.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не то. Я специально привел отдельно блоки с дивами для примера.

Comment: @dropoff а какая разница между реализацией? У вас кстати граватар похож на коловрат. Прикольно.

Comment: блоки не внутри меню, а отдельно)
Я же не вариант реализации прошу, а советов по определенной проблеме с которой столкнулся))

Comment: >>У вас кстати граватар похож на коловрат. Прикольно
действительно) не заметил бы. спасибо))

Comment: Вот так вот http://jsfiddle.net/3ehGE/
Только как тут можно теперь сделать, чтобы не закрывало див при переходе от пункта меню к блоку дива.
Т.е. как в вашем примере, только блоки отдельно должны быть.
Можно такое вообще сделать?

Comment: [Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3ehGE/2/) подойдёт?